# Notify when a formula updates an Excel cell

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

Consider this specific spreadsheet for an example, but I need an general solution to work as a VSTO Excel add-in.

- A1: contains the number **5**.
- B1: contains a function `=(A1*3)`, which displays **15**.

When a change is made to A1, I want to get notified about it *and* the resulting formula's update in B1.

Using VSTO, I can sink the Application.SheetChange event, which provides the Range representing A1, but I don't get notified that B1's display value also changed. I discovered the Application.SheetCalculate event, but it doesn't seem to have any useful arguments.

```
Application.SheetChange += (sheet, range) => Debug.WriteLine($"Column: {range.Column}, Row: {range.Row}");
Application.SheetCalculate += sh =>
{
    var sheet = sh as Excel.Worksheet;
    Debug.WriteLine($"Sheet: {sheet.Name}"); // need a Range
};
```

In an abstract implementation, is it possible to get notified when a cell containing a function (B1 above) updates its presented value?

Comment: To detect a change you'd need to store the values for the cell(s) of interest and check for updates when the `SheetCalculate` event is triggered.

Comment: Problem is I won't know which cells have formulas ahead of time. The add-in has to work on an unknown workbook and the list changes to value cells as well as formula-calculated cells.

Comment: Do you want a notification if the re-calculation does not change the result??

Comment: No, just when the result changes.

Comment: Add-in has to track all changes on a sheet, not just restricted to specific ranges?  That's going to involve tracking potentially very large amounts of data...  Even the `Sheetchange` event is going to need to do more work: right now your code assumes that `range` is a single cell, but in fact it can be a range of arbitrary size and shape. For the Calculate event, your add-in would have to start by auditing the UsedRange on the sheet, identifying all cells with formulas, and storing their current values so that you could compare them with later iterations following the Calculate event.

Comment: Ah, I was afraid you were going to say that, Tim. I figured an ideal solution was going to be a little CPU heavy, but it sounds like it's going to have a serious performance overhead. Thanks.

Comment: Hypothetically, could it make more sense to do something like a before / after based on saving a ghost sheet at certain intervals (say every 5 minutes), and comparing values on the ghost sheet to what was previously saved? If you do this every time calculate is run it might be worse for performance than any other method, but if you do it periodically it might be okay.

Comment: Could you describe your purpose down here in the comments? Maybe someone can suggest an alternative way of accomplishing your goal that would be easier to implement.

Comment: To expand on @TimWilliams's comment, you could create a directed graph of formula chains by iterating over the `UsedRange` and then iterating over the `Precendents` of each cell. Anytime the regular `SheetChange` event is triggered, you can look up each cell in the directed graph to find all the other cells which would be affected by it.

Comment: Grade Eh: Interesting, so use a ghost sheet as a sort of temp table to do my change tracking. I'll give it ongoing consideration, but I think it might wind up being simpler for me to keep it in C#.
Blackhawk: I think you have just about nailed down the API details of the implementation I want to try first. I'll post the solution with proper creds when I get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much to add beyond the comments to the OP. Thanks, Tim Williams and Blackhawk.

In summary, it's possible to create a directed graph when a spreadsheet loads and then use the graph on the SheetCalculate event to identify which cells are affected in the workbook. The chief downside is that the solution does not scale well to large spreadsheets, as [re]building the graph is an O(n^3) operation.

**[EDIT]**
Turns out the business goals we're trying to achieve have already been accomplished. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-you-can-do-with-Spreadsheet-Inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42. Coupled with Microsoft ACM and DRA Servers, it's a sweet suite.